# Access thrown exception in DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

Is it possible to access the exception in Catch Exception Strategy -> Transform Message component ? I know I can access it via **MEL #[exception.cause]** but I wasn't able to find anything about how to access it in DataWeave.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm curious what's the use case here? If weave throws an exception while transformation, you could catch that in Catch Exception Strategy and if you're trying to transform an exception payload through weave, then I'd say use Mule templates not weave

Comment: Yes the use case is that I need to construct a notification that will be pushed back to CloudHub and I prefer to do all transformations with DataWeave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set exception in payload (like @Ralph Rimorin suggested) or you can set it as variable and use in dw -

```
<catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <logger message="#[exception.message]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
        <set-variable variableName="exception" value="#[exception]"
            doc:name="Set Exception to FlowVars"
            doc:description="This is to ensure that exception object is avaiable to Send Support Email component which uses exception from flowVars instead of the one set by mule at #[exception] as it sometimes tend to get lost."></set-variable>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
a:flowVars.exception
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>


    </catch-exception-strategy>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Lukas, if you catch the exception via flow reference, then the calling flow would be able to evaluate the exception using dataweave. Inside the Catch Exception Strategy, try to set the exception as a payload then in the calling flow, which you have the dataweave would process that.

Comment: Thanks Ralph, it's just that I needed to extract the cause from the exception and append some additional info (all in Catch Exception Strategy) before pushing it to an external system.